# Is there a notation for multiplying block matrix by "scalar" matrix (ie multiply each block individually)?

Tags: matrices, notation, block-matrices

Is there a notation for the question mark place?
A and B are standard real general matrices.
AB means standard matrix multiplication of A and B.

$$
\begin{pmatrix} AB & AB \\ AB & AB \end{pmatrix} = A \, ? \, \begin{pmatrix} B & B \\ B & B \end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that blockwise multiplication by $A$ is the same as multiplying by the block-diagonal matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & A \end{bmatrix}.$$
In the past, I've used various notations to refer to the above, such as $[[A]]$ and Diag($A$), and just made sure to define my notation before using it.

That said, I'm also curious whether a standard notation exists.

Comment: Of course, the diagonal trick completely slipped my mind, thanks for reminding me! It's good enough for me, even though of course, having a standard notation for it would be even better. Cheers.

Comment: One more thing came to my mind. What if A is a scalar and B a matrix? The diagonal trick wouldn't technically work then anymore, since the dimensions would not match necessarily. You know, A*B works if A is a scalar and B a matrix, since that is defined separately. But if you do diag(A), this would create a matrix that would not match in dimensions with the block matrix of B's.